# Iphone SDk Sound On/off Using UISwitch Button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

how can i turn on/off sound in iphone sdk using UISWITCH button ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot turn the sound on or off systemwide using the SDK.

Comment: well i can turn on/off sound in one view of music player application but i want to put this on/off function in other view and i dont know how to do this